# MySQL: Using WHERE clause in subquery in JOIN gives error when outer table's column is referenced

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query a couple of tables with a JOIN using a subquery to narrow down the returned results. When I use a WHERE clause in the subquery which references a value of a column from the outer query I get an error #1054 unknown column in where clause.

I'd like to query the Master table with mode=2 and get relevant records from the Transaction table. If Master.mode=2 and Master.type=1, then get all transactions who's id's match but with type=2 and vice versa. In short, get records from Transaction who's IDs match, but with opposite Type values. In case of more than 1 record, then get the record with the highest 'Amount' from Transaction table.

```
Master table
+----+-----+-------+-------+
|id  |mode |type   |other  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
|1   |1    |1      |11111  |
|2   |2    |2      |22222  |
|3   |2    |1      |33333  |
|4   |1    |2      |44444  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+

Transaction table
+----+-------+-------+
|id  |type   |amount |
+----+-------+-------+
|1   |1      |1000   |
|1   |2      |1000   |
|2   |1      |2000   |
|2   |2      |3000   |
|3   |1      |500    |
|3   |1      |5000   |
|3   |1      |3000   |
|3   |2      |4000   |
|3   |2      |2000   |
|4   |1      |1000   |
|4   |2      |2000   |
|1   |1      |3000   |
+----+-------+-------+

Expected Result
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|id  |mode |type   |other  |amount |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|2   |2    |2      |22222  |2000   |
|3   |2    |1      |33333  |4000   |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+

My query
SELECT t1.*, t2.Amount
FROM master AS t1
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT t3.*
                FROM transactions AS t3
                WHERE t3.id=t1.id AND t3.Type=(CASE WHEN t1.Type=1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
                ORDER BY t3.Amount DESC
                LIMIT 1
        ) AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.Mode=2 AND t2.Type=(CASE WHEN t1.Type=1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
```

I get an error **#1054 - Unknown column 't1.id' in 'where clause'**

Comment: Was that a question, or a status report? MySQL doesn't support correlated subquery as an inline view (called a *derived table* in the MySQL venacular.) `t2` is in the `FROM` clause. It's a rowsource for the outer query. MySQL materializes the view as a derived table *before* the outer query runs. Values from the outer query are not available when the view is materialized.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks! Any ideas how I could achieve my intended result? I had prepared my query based on similar answers I had seen on SO but it seems my logic is incorrect. Can you help with the corrected logic?

Comment: Looks like we could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the expected result. we could start with a query like this:

```
 SELECT m.id
      , m.mode
      , m.type
      , m.other
   FROM master m
  WHERE m.mode = 2
  ORDER BY ...
```

And for each row returned by that query, it looks like we want to get a single value. We can use a correlated subquery to get the value, for example:

```
 SELECT t.amount
   FROM transactions t
  WHERE t.id   = m.id 
    AND t.type = IF(m.type=2,1,2)
  ORDER BY t.amount DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

The correlated subquery returns a single column, and returns no more than one row, so we can include that in the SELECT list of the original query.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT m.id
      , m.mode
      , m.type
      , m.other
      , ( SELECT t.amount
            FROM transactions t
           WHERE t.id   = m.id 
             AND t.type = IF(m.type=2,1,2)
           ORDER BY t.amount DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS `Amount`
   FROM master m
  WHERE m.mode = 2 
  ORDER BY ...
```

The way this works is that the outer query (query from master) is executed. For each row returned, the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated. Evaluating expressions like `m.id`, `m.mode`, `m.type` are pretty straightforward, and each returns a scalar value which gets put into the resultset.

Evaluating the correlated subquery works the same way. It's a little more complicated... MySQL executes the subquery, using the values of the current `m` row, and returns a single value, which gets put into the resultset.

**NOTE:**

If the correlated subquery doesn't return a row, a NULL gets put into the resultset.

If the specification is to return only rows with a non-NULL value in the amount column, we can add a `HAVING` clause

```
 WHERE m.mode = 2 
HAVING `Amount` IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY ...
```

Also note:

Because that correlated subquery is executed for *each* row returned by the outer query, for a lot of rows from master, thats a lot of subquery executions, which can drag down performance for large sets.

That makes it very important to have a suitable index available for subquery.
Ideally, a covering index ...

```
ON transaction (id, type, amount)
```